# Mail Chimp RSS issues

Tags: wordpress, rss, mailchimp

I've created a newsletter using the RSS feed and duplicated this news letter for my organisation (I've done this to reduce work at weekends and automate it) So I have

1. Mon - Fri newsletter
2. Saturday Newsletter
3. Sunday newsletter

I'm finding that on Monday, Saturday and Sunday the RSS feed is dragging in items that are out of date. Initially (prior to my time) it was believed to be set to drag through the items of a 24 hours period from 5.59pm to 6pm the next day. On the Mon, Sat and Sun I'm now getting reams of news items rather than say, the last 8 to be produced.
I've looked into the code - to see if there is a way to restrict the number of items and have tried that to no avail, and am wondering if there is a way to edit the feed directly in the back of Wordpress. I've tried numerous things. Below is the code I have in my RSS block - it works fine tue- to fri but it needs to work all week through!

*Please click on the links below to take you to today's stories:*

***|RSSITEMS:|***

**Read: *|RSSITEM:TITLE|*** 

***|END:RSSITEMS|***

*Our new-look newsletter has been live for over two weeks now. We'd love to hear what you think, whether that's good, bad or indifferent. Let us know, email Charley at letters@thestrayferret.co.uk*

I found the article that someone mentioned FEEDITEMS $count = 5 but that didn't seem to work
I'm trying to find how to edit the actual feed in WP but its not working - is it worth me setting up a new feed?